# Problem with using VBA to insert formula in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I recently ran into an issue when using VBA to insert a formula into an Excel sheet. Below the relevant piece of code;

```
Calculatie_cell.Offset(n, 5) = "=SOM(H" & (n + 3 - 1) & ":H" & (n + 3 - Onderdelen_aantal) & ")"
Calculatie_cell.Offset(n, 8) = "=SOM(K" & (n + 3 - 1) & ":K" & (n + 3 - Onderdelen_aantal) & ")"
```

For the first iteration where it triggers, the expected output is;

```
=SOM(H4:H7)
=SOM(K4:K7)
```

The output I recieve is;

```
=@SOM(H4:H7)
=@SOM(K4:K7)
```

This output yields a #NAME? error. Pressing F2, enter on the cell (like inputting it by hand), gives an error stating that this formula is not supported by older versions of Excel with the option to correct it to the expected output. If I accept this it works.

I can't find why Excel thinks it needs the @ and the code below does not filter the @ from the formule (but it does filter it out of random text with an @)

```
Calculatie_cell.Offset(n, 5) = Replace(Calculatie_cell.Offset(n, 5), "@", "")
Calculatie_cell.Offset(n, 8) = Replace(Calculatie_cell.Offset(n, 8), "@", "")
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can get rid of the @, or another way to make the formula work? Thanks in advance!

Relevant note; I use Excel 2016 in Dutch, meaning "SOM" is the correct way to spell "SUM"

Comment: Try putting “SUM” in the code - I seem to remember a similar question where it was pointed out vba wants English for functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, regardless of your Office installation language, VBA asks for engligh input.
Therefore, replace `SOM` by `SUM` in your code.
It should appear as `SOM` in the workbook, but not in the code.

Second of all, using `oCell = "=SOME_FORMULA"` usually does not yield the intended result.
Instead, one should use `oCell.Formula2 = "=SOME_FORMULA"`.
This is why an `@` shows up in the formula.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/range-formula-vs-formula2) article for information.

---

Finally, your code should be

```vb
Calculatie_cell.Offset(n, 5).Formula2 = "=SUM(H" & (n + 3 - 1) & ":H" & (n + 3 - Onderdelen_aantal) & ")"
Calculatie_cell.Offset(n, 8).Formula2 = "=SUM(K" & (n + 3 - 1) & ":K" & (n + 3 - Onderdelen_aantal) & ")"
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer! As user Solar Mike mentioned, the issue was indeed using "SOM" instead of "SUM". ALthough the code does work without ".Formula2", I shall add it to prevent issues in the future, Thanks!

Comment: It's a question of how formulas are evaluated by Excel, especially in arrays. `Formula2` refers to a more modern way of evaluating formulas, which has been the standard for quite a few years. Very well written first question by the way, congrats!

Comment: Thank you! I know the struggles of troubeshooting problems with people not giving proper information.
And thanks for the additional info concerning formula2. As stated in my bio, I learn something new everyday I work with VBA!

Answer (score 1):

User @Solar Mike was right.

Even though Excel wants the code to be "SOM" (Dutch spelling), in VBA it needs to ben SUM (English spelling). It auto-translates and works right of the bat. Thank you for your help!

If you post it as an answer, I will accept it as such.